# How should I name a method that does this...?

Tags: language-agnostic

I have a method that receives two range endpoints - start of range and end of range and an integer.

It checks to see if the integer falls between the two end points and returns either the integer or the corresponding end point if the integer falls outside the boundary.

Example 1:

- RangeStart = 0; RangeEnd = 10; Value = 5; Returns 5

Example 2:

- RangeStart = 0; RangeEnd = 10; Value = -4; Returns 0

Example 3:

- RangeStart = 0; RangeEnd = 10; Value = 23; Returns 10

Question: What should I call a method that does that?  I had called it IntWithinRange, but I don't think I like that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about `ConstrictToRange` / `LimitToRange` / `ConfineToRange`? Something of this form would be seem to convey the meaning quite succinctly.

Comment: I like that, it's simple and it's fairly obvious

Comment: `Confine` is another good synonym, as another poster points out. They're all equally good in my view.

Comment: I ended up picking ConfineToRange and making it an extension of integer so that I can do things like MyValue.ConfineToRange(StartRange, EndRange); Thanks for the inspiration.

Comment: You're welcome. And yeah, implementing it as an extension method is a good idea I think.

Answer (score 10):

I've seen it called Clamp().

And that's what M$ calls it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.mathhelper.clamp.aspx

Comment: I guess if that's what Microsoft calls it, it must be right :P

Comment: Clamp is what i thought of too!

Comment: Clamp is simple, but doesn't have as obvious a meaning as the names I suggested IMO.

Comment: I believe that's also the mathematical term as well.

Comment: Names are weird.  Imagine if you had to name sin() and cos() functions.  Some might suggest OppositeOverHypotenuse()...

Comment: Yeah, it's all about what's widely understood.

Comment: @Jeremy: Never come across it in maths. I would think it's just restricted to programming.

Answer (score 7):

```
confine_to(start, end, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

GetBoundedValue?

Answer (score 1):

**normalize**

Comment: In digital music this kind of process is called Quantizing - so I think I like Normalize...

Answer (score 1):

A short one: `Squeeze()`.

Answer (score 0):

BoundedValue() or GetBoundedValue()

Some of the other names sound to me like you're modifying something.